# SaveToStream then write to BLOB mess up the Excel file

Tags: vb.net, blob, memorystream, spreadsheetgear

I'm trying to save a SpreadsheetGear Excel workbook to a BLOB field thru a DbAdapter

```
Try
    Dim stream As New System.IO.MemoryStream()
    customFormatWorkBook.SaveToStream(stream, SpreadsheetGear.FileFormat.Excel8)
    Dim bytes(stream.Length - 1) As Byte
    stream.Read(bytes, 0, stream.Length)
    docDataSet.Tables(0).Rows(0)("FORMATTED_DOC") = bytes
    stream.Close()
Catch ex As Exception
End Try
docDataAdapter.Update(docDataSet, "DOCUMENTS")
```

This code saves a completely messed up Excel file.
If I export it from the DB it even crashes MS Excel *(mmh.. good exception handling Microsoft!)*

Just before `Dim bytes(stream.Length - 1) As Byte` the `stream` is perfectly readable (I tried re-opening it with SpreadsheetGear's `OpenFromStream` method)

Also, I verified that saving to a file, then loading it in a `FileStream`, transforming to a `Byte()` and saving to BLOB also works fine, but I just don't want to access the file system:

```
customFormatWorkBook.SaveAs("C:\Users\teejay\Desktop\prova.xls", SpreadsheetGear.FileFormat.Excel8)

Try    
    Dim stream As FileStream = New FileStream("C:\Users\teejay\Desktop\prova.xls", FileMode.Open)
    Dim bytes(stream.Length - 1) As Byte
    stream.Read(bytes, 0, stream.Length)
    docDSet.Tables(0).Rows(0)("FORMATTED_DOC") = bytes
    stream.Close()
Catch ex As Exception
End Try
docDataAdapter.Update(docDataSet, "DOCUMENTS")
```

Can you help me?

Comment: Before reading the stream, try setting `stream.Position = 0;` so you are 'back at the start of the stream' again. The `SaveToStream` function may not reposition the stream correctly. The second argument in `stream.Read` is your current offset, not position=0

Comment: @dash Thank you!!!!! `FileStream` repositions the stream, but SSG's `SaveToStream` doesn't (position was 512, seems quite random!). Please write your comment as an answer, so I can accept it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the issue is that `SaveToStream` is leaving you at the `end` of the stream; unfortunately, `stream.Read(bytes, 0, stream.Length)` will still work; it will just read 0 bytes into your array. You can verify this by checking the return value from `stream.Read`, which is the total number of bytes read.

So, if you set the `stream.Position` to 0 before attempting to read it:

```
Try
    Dim stream As New System.IO.MemoryStream()
    customFormatWorkBook.SaveToStream(stream, SpreadsheetGear.FileFormat.Excel8)
    stream.Position = 0;
    Dim bytes(stream.Length - 1) As Byte
    stream.Read(bytes, 0, stream.Length)
    docDataSet.Tables(0).Rows(0)("FORMATTED_DOC") = bytes
    stream.Close()
Catch ex As Exception
End Try
docDataAdapter.Update(docDataSet, "DOCUMENTS")
```

Then that should work.